# How to redirect to local html page in phonegap android app?

Tags: jquery, android, html, redirect, cordova

I am trying to create a android app with phonegap, the first page is the login page, it queries to a server for user authentication, the server returns json string: true if the login is successful or false otherwise. I am getting the response but i am not able to redirect to next html page. I am using the below code

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function(){
    var uid = $('#login').val();
    var pwd = $('#password').val();

    $.getJSON('http://example.com/phonegap/login.php',
        { userid: uid, password: pwd },
        function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(k, v) {
                if(v == "true" || v == true){
                    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/page2.html");
                } else {
                    $('#loginError').html("Login failed, username and/or password don't match");
                }
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Please let me know, how can I redirect the user to page2.html after successful login?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can call other html pages using **window.location** and if your second html page present in www folder dont give full path (Please remove your native way path). 
Please check out following code.

```
$('#loginForm').submit(function(){
    var uid = $('#login').val();
    var pwd = $('#password').val();
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/phonegap/login.php',
        { userid: uid, password: pwd },
        function(json) {
            $.each(json, function(k, v) {
                if(v == "true" || v == true){
                    window.location="page2.html";
                } else {
                    $('#loginError').html("Login failed, username and/or password don't match");
                }
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you solved my problem. I was struggling with this issue since 2-3 days.

Comment: Using PhoneGap 1.5.0, jquery 1.7.1 and jquery mobile 1.0.1 this results in a "JSCallback Server Closed: Stopping callbacks." error (at least in my case) disabling scripts after the redirect. Using the jquery function "$.mobile.changePage('url');" everything works fine.

Comment: window .location will redirect but it is changing the webview setting

Comment: Will it load the new redirected page in a webview ? Does jquery mobile also does the same thing i.e. changes window.location

Comment: Thanks you saved my life :)

Answer (score 1):

from a pure javascript perspective,
Will `window.location.href = 'something.html';` not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery load method

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I have to redirect rather than loading its content in a html tag.. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

karnyj is right, as the marked solution is bugged for iOS.  Using window.location = "url" will sometimes freeze the application in iOS (happens every time I restart the device).

//This is the way to go
window.location.href = 'something.html';

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths should be fine.

I have found `window.location = './yourPage.html'` (and
`window.location.href = './yourPage.html'`) don't always work,
and have had success using  : 
**`window.location.replace('./yourPage.html');`**

Answer (score 0):

> window.location.replace('xyz.html');
>   Works always !